# Why does Apache complain that CGI.pm has panicked at line 4001 due to a memory wrap?

Tags: perl, apache

This error according to the logs is caused by a 5-year old Perl script that merely grabs data from MySQL via a simple SQL select and displays it.

It's running on my dev machine which is MBP with 8GB of RAM running the stock Apache.

Once a while, once or twice a month, I get the following error for no apparent reason :

panic: memory wrap at /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/CGI.pm line 4001.

Apache refuses to run the script again and only a reboot of the OS would make Apache relent. The OS says that there's 3+ GB of free memory when it happens so it's not a low memory issue. Luckily this doesn't happen on the production Debian 5 server.

What's a memory wrap? And what causes it?

Comment: `perldoc perldiag` says that "panic: memory wrap" means "Something tried to allocate more memory than possible". A bit of googling suggests that this isn't a CGI.pm problem but an occassional problem with Perl 5.10 and OSX.

Comment: @mu - Your comment should IMO be an answer.

Comment: I totally agree with Nifle. @mu you comment is the answer.

Comment: In the future, please post system administration questions on ServerFault. StackOverflow is only for programming Q&A.

Comment: @Dan Grossman, I concur. This should be in ServerFault.

Comment: Dan & Gene - how was the OP supposed to know that a memory error in CGI.pm code was caused by the underlying OS and not by the Perl code which would of course then be a programming Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit this bug as well in a slightly different circumstance. PerlMonks, as ever, has just saved me probably days of work:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=823389

> the problem lies in the way osx ties
>   up other resources. a simple sleep
>   will give the os time to close and
>   open. restart or graceful will go in
>   conflict.
>
> ```
> apachectl stop
> sleep 2
> apachectl start
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is late but the perl distributed by MacPorts does not have this problem, if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

mu is too short's answer, which as unfortunately posted as a comment. :

perldiag says that "panic: memory wrap" means "Something tried to allocate more memory than possible". A bit of googling suggests that this isn't a CGI.pm problem but an occassional problem with Perl 5.10 and OSX.